# Ansible Arista Interface Module keeps changed state

Tags: ansible, interface, state, eos

I'm trying to configure an Arista 7050 Switch's interfaces with Ansible.

Whenever I run the playbook, it keeps the status "changed". When I use the "fact_diff" module, it shows no output which means, the Ansible "before" and "after" values are the same.
Please find below some code snippets.

The Task in the Playbook:

```
- name: Ensure all Access-Interfaces are configured with a VLANs and mode
  arista.eos.eos_l2_interfaces:
    config:
    - name: Et47
      mode: access
      access:
        vlan: 3
    state: merged
  register: access_if
  tags:
    - interfaces_vlans
    - interfaces_vlans_access
```

Then, I try to find the diffs using this:

```
- name: Show Diffs
  ansible.utils.fact_diff:
    before: "{{ access_if.before }}"
    after: "{{ access_if.after }}"
  tags:
    - interfaces_vlans
    - interfaces_vlans_access
```

For some reasons the output of the "fact_diff" module is like this below, although the "eos_l2_interfaces" module shows changed.

```
ok: [zhloccs11a] => {
    "changed": false,
    "diff": {
        "prepared": ""
    },
    "diff_lines": [],
    "diff_text": ""
}
```

Ansible: 2.11
EOS: 4.18